# Visual Basic.NET resources for C# developer

Tags: c#, vb.net, programming-languages

I am C# developer and now I am involved in some large, already in production, project that is written in Visual Basic.NET.

I am trying hard not to write in C# and use some automatic conversion tool to Visual Basic.NET. I want to be able to read and write fluently in Visual Basic.NET **QUICKLY**. I can write and read VB.NET but it is not so easy like writing and reading C#.

I would be grateful if someone who was in the same situation could share there experience or point to some good resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few quick links. The logic is the same. It's basically just syntax.

[Comparison of C Sharp and Visual Basic .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET)

[C# and VB.NET Comparison Cheat Sheet](http://aspalliance.com/625)

[VB.NET and C# Comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) is a good page that I've used in that situation in the past.  It's not up-to-the-minute accurate, but should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Practice takes time.